# Google Sheets script to copy a range to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to cut and paste a range to another sheet to track the history of prices. I would like the range on "Logging" of B2:D2, B3:D3, and so on; to be copied over to "History" A3:C3, D3:F3, and so on.

So far I have come up with:

```
function moveValues () {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
 var source = ss.getRange("Logging!B2:D2");
 var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("History");
 var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
 source.copyTo (destRange , {contentsOnly: true});
 source.clear ();
}
```

This will take the the data on the Logging sheet B2:D2 and move it to the History sheet A3:C3 but I cant figure out how to copy the remaining vertical data and turn it into a horizontal arrangement on the next sheet.

Thank you.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOSbP.jpg "Sheet0" or "Logging"

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RjYD.jpg "Sheet1" or "History"

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Is the script working? (apparently there is a typo, instead of `car` it should be `var`)

Comment: That was a mistake in the transfer over here. In sheets it is working but not in the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's behaving properly

It's going to the destination sheet to the lastrow plus one

```
function moveValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh = ss.getRange("Sheet0!B2:D2");
  var dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var drg = dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  ssh.copyTo(drg, { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

#### After new data

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const [hA, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let idx = {};
  let col = {};
  let obj = { pA: [] };
  hA.forEach((h, i) => { idx[h] = i; col[h] = i + 1; });
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if (r[2] && r[3]) {
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
        obj[r[0]] = [['', r[0], ''], ['Date', 'High', 'Low'], [r[1], r[2], r[3]]];
        obj.pA.push(r[0]);
      } else {
        obj[r[0]].push([[r[1]], r[2], r[3]]);//for follow on data with identical item names
      }
    }
  });
  obj.pA.forEach((p, i) => {
    osh.getRange(1, (i * 3) + 1, obj[p].length, obj[p][0].length).setValues(obj[p]);
  });
  osh.clear();
  osh.getRange('1:2').setFontWeight('bold');
}
```

Input Data/Sheet:

| Item | Date | Low | High |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | Date1 | Low1 | High1 |
| Item2 | Date2 | Low2 | High2 |
| Item3 | Date3 | Low3 | High3 |
| Item4 | Date4 | Low4 | High4 |
| Item5 | Date5 | Low5 | High5 |
| Item7 | Date7 |  |  |
| Item6 | Date6 |  |  |
| Item8 | Date8 |  |  |
| Item9 | Date9 |  |  |
| Item10 | Date10 |  |  |
| Item11 | Date11 |  |  |
| Item12 | Date12 |  |  |
| Item13 | Date13 |  |  |
| Item14 | Date14 |  |  |

Output Sheet:

|  | Item1 |  |  | Item2 |  |  | Item3 |  |  | Item4 |  |  | Item5 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Date | High | Low | Date | High | Low | Date | High | Low | Date | High | Low | Date | High | Low |
| Date1 | Low1 | High1 | Date2 | Low2 | High2 | Date3 | Low3 | High3 | Date4 | Low4 | High4 | Date5 | Low5 | High5 |

Image:

[image]

Comment: Right. This is behaving properly. But I can't figure out how to get it to do a bit more as I explained. I would like Sheet0!B2:D2, Sheet0!B3:D3, Sheet0!B3:D3, and so on to be copied to Sheet1!A3:C3, Sheet1!D3:F3, Sheet1!G3:I3, and so on. While any new data set that gets entered into Sheet0 gets copied to the next row down on Sheet1.
Does that make sense?

Comment: So you are saying that you want the new data to overwrite the  old data?

Comment: No. I want this to transfer the data from sheet one to sheet two transposing it from columns to a row. The data from sheet0 will be deleted by source.clear but the data will remain on sheet1. Then the new data on sheet0 will be pasted over on the next row down.

Comment: Please a create a couple of images showing us the way the data looks on the first sheet and how you want it to look on the second sheet

Comment: I added images to the original post.

Comment: Did you actually expect us to have figured that out on our own? If so, you certainly are crediting me with a lot more intelligence than I possess.  Hopefully someone can provide you with an answer soon.  If not, I will return after some sleep.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought I had explained it well enough between the OP and the first reply to you. It probably just made more sense to me because I was working on it and you were coming in from the outside. Next time I have a question I will make sure to provide more detail and pictures to make it easier right off the bat. Thank you for asking the questions you needed answered and for taking the time to lend a hand.

Comment: Try taking another look.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works great. This is well beyond my skill levels so I don't know where I could add in the lastrow +1 bit.

Comment: I don't understand the last part of you most recent comment `I don't know where I could add in the lastrow +1 bit`

Comment: When running the script multiple times it overwrites the data. The original script I wrote would write to the next empty row. Can I add that functionality in to what you wrote?

Comment: Try it now.  It will clear the output sheet and rebuild it.

Comment: That just completely deletes the output sheet now.

Comment: Well do what you want I have no idea what your output sheet looks like.  Our mission here is to answer focused questions not solve all of your problems for you.  Put your thinking cap on and dive in

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all your help.